# sed to print pattern that spans across lines

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression

I'm learning sed and I'm currently stuck with the following problem:

I want to extract the lines found between `^C`'s from the following output:

```
banner exec ^C
This is
the
banner
^C
banner motd ^C
This is
the MOTD
banner
^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
```

I'm using [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51b) as a reference, but it doesn't seem like a good idea if you don't know how many lines you will be capturing. What would be the best way to deal with this?

Comment: which `^C`s are you trying to extract between? When you write `^C` do you mean CTRL+C or do you mean literal circumflex and capital C?

Comment: I mean literal `^C`

Comment: As requested by gogoud, you should clarify how you wish it to be extracted as that part is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should work, assuming source data is in file test.txt, this uses grep to exclude the lines that contain the '^C':

```
sed -n '/\^C/,/\^C/p' test.txt|grep -v '\^C'
```

Output from your example:

```
This is
the
banner
This is
the MOTD
banner
```

Comment: This works as well and is more readable

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured it out. It seems like this does the trick:

```
sed -n '/\^C/,/\^C/{/\^C/!{p}}' input
```

Apparently you can run sed between two matched regexes, so I just put the same regex as beginning and end `/\^C/,/\^C/` and then printed the lines, skipping the last line containing that same pattern.

I don't know if this is the best method, but it seems to work.